Authenticator is required to verify startup disk
I have a 13" M1 MacBook Pro (2020). Recently it has been restarting immediately after logging in and showing a popup stating "Authentication is required to verify startup disk". After entering my password, the Mac boots to the login screen, I login, the computer works fine for a minute or two, then immediately restarts again.
I took it to the Apple Store. They ran diagnostics but couldn't find any hardware issues. They helped me erase my SSD and reinstall MacOS - it worked fine for an hour or two of active use. But now the restarting loop is back as I described earlier. I've tried running first aid through disk utility but everything seems normal. Could it just be a hardware issue still? Has anyone ever encountered this issue?
EDIT: The problem seems to be related to disk I/O. My mac seemed to work fine after not using it for a couple hours - however as soon as I tried downloading some large data the computer restarted. I was curious about this so I wrote (i.e. asked ChatGPT to write) a Python script which spawns a couple processes and writes to /tmp. Whenever I run that script, the Mac will reboot by itself.

Please boot in Safe Mode and test. Any difference?

Did you buy the Mac brand new, or secondhand? When you reinstalled OS, did you get the "Hello" startup? It seems like the security/encryption/ authentication of the disk is corrupted in some way. It's possibly that you can fix this with Apple Configurator (connecting it to another Mac).

@LincDavis There's no difference. I actually found something interesting related to disk operations and updated my question.

@benwiggy It was a brand new Mac, and yes I go the "Hello" and other startup menus when the OS was reinstalled.

It sounds like the System volume is failing an integrity check. That should never happen, so I think you're dealing with a hardware fault. A negative diagnostic check doesn't rule that out.
